# Sierra: alias in .bash_profile not working

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, vnc

I can't seem to figure out how to create a bash alias in terminal on my current mac. I'm on Sierra and did

1.) `nano .bash_profile`

2.) I added the following 2nd line: 
[image]

3.) when running `vnc` I get "command not found"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Alias means **mapping**, mapping `vnc` to `37.125.59.151:6116` means when you type `vnc` `37.125.59.151:6116` "command" is executed, and commands are usually verbs or nouns, not numbers and dots :)

What you need might be *variable*.

Variables contain the value what can be accessed by prepending `$` into their names.

---

In Linux (`bash` shell on Fedora) the global variable's value is usually set in `.bashrc` file as `export EDITOR=vim` for instance.

Comment: Ok, sorry, but I don't want to remember the IP but want to just call "vnc" in the terminal and fire the entire thing to connect to this specific ip and port, is that possible?

Comment: @Matt I think you should alias vnc to vnc and the IP address. Alias vnc=vnc <IP> or other VNC client app to open the servers IP with. I mean the address should be followed by the application.

Comment: Pick something other than "vnc" as the name, and alias it to "vnc 37.125.59.151:6116". Like this: `alias vnc_myserver='vnc 37.125.59.151:6116'`